# Azure Backups Failing Due To Possible MARS Agent DLL Issue

Tags: azure, backup, sql-server-mars

We are running Microsoft Azure Backup Server (MABS) v3 on Windows Server 2019. Since Monday evening the cloud and bare-metal backups started failing, but other on-premises backups are running fine.

Looking through Event Viewer we found an application error which might assist in resolving the issue, but I haven't been able to find much info online:

```
Faulting application name: cbengine.exe, version: 2.0.9177.0, time stamp: 0x5e677965
Faulting module name: LKRhDPM.DLL, version: 2.0.9177.0, time stamp: 0x5e6778b2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005e3f
Faulting process id: 0x1984
Faulting application start time: 0x01d62470ae5f7af9
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Backup Server\DPM\MARS\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\bin\cbengine.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Backup Server\DPM\MARS\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\bin\LKRhDPM.DLL
Report Id: b57ddf2b-4948-4f68-b572-e58f9031db9b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The application is on the most recent version and I also updated and repaired all the Visuall C++ components as well as .NET frameworks.

The OS also has the March updates installed.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why, but the cause of the issues was the latest version of Sysinternals' Sysmon, version 11.0.

This also caused another issue where Office documents would take long to open or save from and to network locations, even when the client had a gigabit connection to the server.

Rolling back to Sysmon version 10.42 resolved all of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try upgrading to the latest version of Sysmon (12.02). They corrected this issue there.

Comment: Thanks, we are in the process of testing the new version, and I can confirm the issues were resolved.

It also fixes a BSOD issue we started experiencing with 10.42 on our Dell Latitude E7450 and older notebooks. BSODs would start soon after drivers are installed via Windows Update (Windows Update for Business), even though Dell's own drivers are already installed and automatic driver updates are blocked client and Intune side.

Initially, we suspected a buggy driver released via Windows Update, but minidumps suggested Sysmon's driver to be the culprit.